# Does XMLHttpRequest.onreadystatechange still gets called under the hood when we use Promises?

Tags: javascript, ajax, promise

Let us say I am using a `Promisified` API for making an `Ajax Request`, even then the `event-loop` would still call the plain old `XMLHttpRequest.onreadystatechange` right?

I mean *Promisfying* is a nice way to write code in a sequential style, but under the hood what happens is still the plain old mechanisms right? A bit like the `class` syntax in `ECMASCRIPT 6`. In other words, the core API's are still the same?

I can't see how we can register a `Promise` directly to an `event-loop`, because there should be some logic should be there which would "resolve" or "reject", so a simple wrapper has to exists [that can be implemented a promise too, I don't know if it would lead to too much promises]?

Comment: The implementation of these promises completely depends on the library implementing it. But yes, it would be a logical approach.

Comment: What is the question you want an answer to? Is your logic logical? Yes. Do the *Promisified API* register to some event? If they are really building over XHR then yes most probably (would be a shame to make a polling loop for this). If they are using an already built-in promise based API like fetch then no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Let us say I am using a Promisified API for making an Ajax Request, even then the event-loop would still call the plain old XMLHttpRequest.onreadystatechange right?

There are several ways to make Ajax requests.

A library which wrapped a promise around XHR *could* use a `readystatechange` event. It could use `load` and `error` events.

A promise-based Ajax library could avoid XHR entirely.

It could use JSONP.

`fetch` is supported natively in browsers, is promise based, and doesn't go near XHR.

> A bit like the class syntax in ECMASCRIPT 6. In other words, the core API's are still the same?

No.

Promises are a standardised API, not just different syntax to do the same things as existing code.

Comment: So just trying to visualize the event-loop, would it be calling the Promise directly, if so which one would it call - `resolve` or `reject`? Unless there is a wrapper to decide which one,  can't imagine how it is done. Anyways, I will check the `fetch` API.

Comment: Probably this explains that? *It returns a Promise that resolves to the Response to that request, whether it is successful or not.*
This is from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API.